# Login for Android App using Google Appengine Backend

Tags: android, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am developing an Application with a google appengine backend where I want the user to be able to login.

It should be possible to login with Facebook, Google+ and my own login(for those users who don't have any fb or google account). Also it should be possible that when the user starts the app he shouldn't need to log in again if he didn't logged out before. So a valid token is requested somehow.

I already implemented the facebook login which uses sessions and a helper that handles all that stuff.

Thats all fine. But what I couldn't really figure out yet is what would be a right way to implement my own login. Is it right that this can be done with the Android AccountManager and Oauth2.0? If yes I don't really know how to combine that with the facebook login because that uses it's own facebook token. Would I need to handle two tokens then for a user that logs in with facebook and calls authanticated requests?

There are so many apps who have those three possibilities are they all using their own selfmade login procedure for the own app login, or is this done somehow with the AccountManager or something else in general?

Can somebody explain this to me or point me in the right direction or just give a little overview because I am just confused right now with all this.